# Adding 'counts' column to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes, I will call them frame1 and frame2. frame1 is the smaller frame, and has an id column, where every single id is unique. frame2 is larger and has the exact same id column, but many of the ids are duplicated. However the number of unique ids in frame2, is the same amount of rows in frame1... aka, every id in frame2 exists in frame1.

What I am trying to do is add a 'counts' column to frame1 that consists of the number of unique metric categories associated with each id in frame2.

here is what the frames would look like:

[image]

so, I would like to add the column 'unique_metric_counts' into frame1 that would have '3' for id 1, '2' for id 2, and '1' for id 3.

I have a pretty good idea of how to do this, the problem is that I believe it takes up WAY to much memory in my Jupyter Notebook and will never finish running, as it is a for loop over a very big frame, and in the for loop I am creating temporary frames of an even larger frame.

Here is my code:

```
frame1['unique_metric_counts'] = None

for x in frame1['id']:
    tempframe = frame2[frame2['id'].isin([x])]
    numUnique = tempframe['metric categories'].nunique()
    frame1['unique_metric_counts'] = numUnique
```

I am fairly certain that this code should work in theory, but my dataframes are absolutely massive, and I think it would be way better to not use a for loop, but just use Pandas functionality. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that creates a lookup from the "metric_categories" values in frame 2, and then maps to the row in frame 1 corresponding to the ids in the lookup keys:

```
# Create dataframes

ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
feat = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'some_feature':feat})

ids = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]
feat = ['aa','aa','aa','bb','bb','bb','bb','cc','cc','cc']
metrics = ['metric x', 'metric y', 'metric z','metric x', 'metric x','metric z', 'metric z','metric x', 'metric x', 'metric x']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'some_feature':feat, 'metric_categories':metrics})


# Create mapping (a dictionary where keys are the 'id' and values are the length of the set of the 'metric categories'):
 
mapping = df2.groupby('id')['metric_categories'].agg(lambda x: len(set(x))).to_dict()

mapping
# >>> {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}


# Map dictionary to 'id' column in df1:

df1['unique_metric_counts'] = df1['id'].map(mapping)

print(df1)

#    id     some_feature    unique_metric_counts
# 0   1           aa                   3.0
# 1   2           bb                   2.0
# 2   3           cc                   1.0
# 3   4           dd                   NaN
# 4   5           ee                   NaN
```

Comment: If there's a key in the dictionary for each `id` in df1 then you won't get NaNs in `unique_metric_counts` and then pandas will know that the datatype is an int (and not a float like is shown in the print above)